# Multiple threads adding and removing items to a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I have the below code that works fine in other applications.

In my application I have 4 threads calling a AddToList method every 60ms.

Once it got to 1000 items in a list and began to try and remove items the CPU would go to 100%.  Setting the count down to 100 would fix it.

Any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
public delegate void dgAddToList(string Message, int InputID);

public void AddToList(string Message, int InputID)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      this.BeginInvoke(new dgAddToList(AddToList), new object[] { Message, InputID });
   }
   else
   {

      switch (InputID)
      {
         case 0:
            this.listBox1.Items.Insert(0, Message);

            if (this.listBox1.Items.Count > 100) 
            this.listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(this.listBox1.Items.Count - 1);

            break;

         case 1:
             this.listBox2.Items.Insert(0, Message);

             if (this.listBox2.Items.Count > 100) 
                this.listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(this.listBox2.Items.Count - 1);

             break;

          case 2:
              this.listBox3.Items.Insert(0, Message);

              if (this.listBox3.Items.Count > 100) 
                this.listBox3.Items.RemoveAt(this.listBox3.Items.Count - 1);

               break;

           case 3:
              this.listBox4.Items.Insert(0, Message);

              if (this.listBox4.Items.Count > 100) 
                 this.listBox4.Items.RemoveAt(this.listBox4.Items.Count - 1);

               break;
     }
}
```

}

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify. The first thread will only update Listbox1, the second thread will update Listbox 2. This is determined by the InputID parameter so Thread1 passes 0 and Thread 2 passes 1

Comment: Are you saying you call that code from multiple threads? The code isn't thread safe to begin with, you check the count and then call remove (another thread could have added/removed something meanwhile)? This isn't the source of the performance problem though.

Comment: @Anders the Invoke serializes it. Thread safety is not the issue.

Comment: It sounds to me like you may be better served with a list box (or list view) operating in virtual mode, however that is achieved in WinForms.

Comment: Ah I see. Is the number of threads then really an issue? Would you not get the same performance from 1 thread running at 1/4 the interval time?

Comment: This is used in a Winforms project and multiple threads are calling that method

Comment: I thought that the Invoke made is thread safe.  Maybe a invoke and a lock is required?

Comment: @jon Invoke does make it thread safe because those methods all run on the same thread

Comment: Conflicting opinion to @sll below. See updated question

Comment: @sll is simply wrong. `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` ensure that the delegate is executed on the UI thread. No lock required.

Comment: That's what I thought. Does that mean in my scenario when Thread 1 makes a call to update listBox1 and another comes in quickly, that second method call will wait until the first method is complete

Comment: @Jon Yes they will have to queue up. Why don't use use a ListView in virtual mode? Much more efficient.

Comment: I used a listview to start with and the rendering was more CPU intensive than a listbox. What does virtual mode do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe 60 milliseconds and 4 async threads is a big load for UI messages pipeline so it got stuck. Try out increasing time interval (for instance 200 milliseconds) if this is appropriate from an application behaviour requirements perspectives.

BTW, You can refcator switch statement as shown below so code would be much clear:

```
public void AddToList(string Message, int InputID)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new dgAddToList(AddToList), new object[] { Message, InputID });
    }
    else
    {
        ListBox listBoxInstance = null;

        switch (InputID)
        {
            case 0:
                listBoxInstance = this.listBox1;
                break;
            case 1:
                listBoxInstance = this.listBox2;
                break;
            case 2:
                listBoxInstance = this.listBox3;
                break;
            case 3:
                listBoxInstance = this.listBox4;
                break;
        }

        if (listBoxInstance != null)
        {
             listBoxInstance.Items.Insert(0, Message);
             if (listBoxInstance.Items.Count > 100)
             {
                listBoxInstance.Items.RemoveAt(
                                  listBoxInstance.Items.Count - 1);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no control over the speed of inputs. I know it comes in at 60ms apart but lowering the count fixed it for some reason

Comment: @Jon : basically you are adding a new message at the beginning of the list and then removing last item? BTW, which control type you are using? Can you give full name including namespace?

Comment: Once it hits a certain limit, yes. Its a System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

Comment: have you tried locking an access to listBox instance (entire `if (listBoxInstance != null)` block)? Since it is accessed by multiple threads it colud be messed up somehow. See updated answer

Comment: @Jon : no, it only invokes a delegate in a separate thread but it does not guaranty any thread safety. Try out simple `lock()` for first try

Comment: The use of `BeginInvoke` renders the lock needless. `BeginInvoke` results in the delegate executing on the UI thread.

Comment: @David Heffernan : my bad, will revert back my answer. Thanks for pointing to this

Comment: @David Heffernan : OP said that `4 threads calling a AddToList` so this.BeginInvoke() would be called not from the UI thread, does it mean it pump mesages to UI thread as well since it was not runend by UI thread?

Comment: @sll I don't understand the Q.

Comment: @David Heffernan : sorry, let me rephrase. So `this.BeginInvoke()` called by `AddList()` method. Since `AddList()` called from custom threads (non default UI thread) would this.BeginInvoke() execute delegate in UI thread rather than custom thread?

Comment: It depends what `this` is. My guess is that it is a form and so the invoke will move execution onto UI thread.

Comment: @Jon : what is `this` when you are calling `this.BeginInvoke()`?

Comment: @sll: To be exact, calling `this.Invoke()` or `this.BeginInvoke()` causes the delegate to be executed on the thread that owns the window handle of `this` - which generally means the UI thread.